# is there any way to show a <dialog> as modal without using showModal()?‬

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

the new `<dialog>` element improves accessibility by keeping the keyboard focus inside the dialog

[image: Can-I-Use tabel]

Unfortunately it seems like that the improved focus management works only for the JS api.
As you can see the outer input element is prevented from receiving focus because it is in the background:

```js
document.querySelector("dialog").showModal();
```

```html
<input name="back">

<dialog><input name="front"></dialog>
```

Without `showModal()` the outer input element can be focused although it's in the background.

```html
<input name="back">

<dialog open><input name="front"></dialog>
```

Is there any way to get the same behavior like `showModal()` only with html?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872125/make-modal-without-javascript) will help you.

Comment: In chrome work, which browser do you use? Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) for compatibily

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I added two demos to my question so you can easily see the difference in Chrome

Comment: @jantimon You are right and actually in MDN it says: _"The `::backdrop` CSS pseudo-element can be used to style behind a `<dialog>` element when the dialog is displayed with `HTMLDialogElement.showModal()`. For example, to dim unreachable content behind the modal dialog."_  and in [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element) seems doesn't exist html method.

Comment: Looks like there is only a proposal to add `<dialog type="modal">` https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6730